# Setting GCC 4.2.1 options in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, gcc, arm, intrinsics

I have a few questions about Xcode and interaction with GCC 4.2.1:

1. It doesn't seem as if Xcode Target Properties inspector exposes all possible GCC options. Is this correct?
2. More specifically, I'm interested in setting the "mfpu" option, as mentioned in the arm_neon.h intrinsics header. Is this possible or supported? Or perhaps set as a side-effect of some other Xcode setting?

If anyone has tried this or can post some resources, it would help a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are not checkboxes or menus available each option presented by the compiler, however you can enter any flags you'd like passed to the compiler in the "Other C Flags" field of the Target inspector.

Just set "Other C Flags" to "-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon" and you'll be set.

Comment: Thanks! I just figured that out as well.